# Xcode Swift Error: Framework not found FirebaseAnalytics

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I tried adding FirebaseAnalytics now in getting this error.

This is my pod file:

[image]

And this is the error:

> Framework not found FirebaseAnalytics

tried adding `$(inherited)` in the build settings. tried deleting everything and redoing it.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Did you run `pod install` after updating the Podfile? Are you opening the workspace file and not the project file in Xcode?

Comment: Are you still getting the error? You could also try to clean your build folder and then Build the Project again (Product > Clean Build Folder) after doing a pod update.